# Making calculator using Swing

Tags: java, swing

I have developed the calc using swing but i have a problem in equal to button.
I have written the code for addition,subtraction,multiplication and division in the equal to button but the problem is that when i subtract two numbers I get the o/p but when I add or multiply or divide I don't get the o/p. So help me in
the code of equal to button:

```
package com.dss;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.SoftBevelBorder;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;

public class JCalcEx extends JFrame {  

private JPanel contentPane;
private JTextField value1;
private JTextField value2;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                JCalcEx frame = new JCalcEx();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public JCalcEx() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 395, 680);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    value1 = new JTextField();
    value1.setBorder(new SoftBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, 
    null, null));
    value1.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    value1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    value1.setBounds(12, 69, 350, 41);
    contentPane.add(value1);
    value1.setColumns(10);

    JTextField value3 = new JTextField();
    value3.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    value3.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    value3.setBorder(new SoftBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, 
    null, null));
    value3.setBounds(12, 111, 353, 41);
    contentPane.add(value3);
    value3.setColumns(10);

    JButton button9 = new JButton("9");
    button9.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            value1.setText(value1.getText()+9);
        }
    });
    button9.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    button9.setBounds(12, 192, 69, 70);
    contentPane.add(button9);

    JButton button8 = new JButton("8");
    button8.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
            value1.setText(value1.getText()+8);
        }
    });
    button8.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    button8.setBounds(105, 192, 69, 70);
    contentPane.add(button8);

    JButton button7 = new JButton("7");
    button7.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            value1.setText(value1.getText()+7);
        }
    });
    button7.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    button7.setBounds(199, 192, 69, 70);
    contentPane.add(button7);

    JButton button6 = new JButton("6");
    button6.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            value1.setText(value1.getText()+6);
        }
    });
    button6.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    button6.setBounds(293, 192, 69, 70);
    contentPane.add(button6);

    JButton button5 = new JButton("5");
    button5.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            value1.setText(value1.getText()+5);
        }
    });
    button5.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    button5.setBounds(12, 293, 69, 70);
    contentPane.add(button5);

    JButton button4 = new JButton("4");
    button4.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            value1.setText(value1.getText()+4);
        }
    });
    button4.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    button4.setBounds(105, 293, 69, 70);
    contentPane.add(button4);

    JButton button3 = new JButton("3");
    button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            value1.setText(value1.getText()+3);
        }
    });
    button3.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    button3.setBounds(199, 293, 69, 70);
    contentPane.add(button3);

    JButton button2 = new JButton("2");
    button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            value1.setText(value1.getText()+2);
        }
    });
    button2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    button2.setBounds(293, 293, 69, 70);
    contentPane.add(button2);

    JButton button1 = new JButton("1");
    button1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            value1.setText(value1.getText()+1);
        }
    });
    button1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    button1.setBounds(12, 392, 69, 70);
    contentPane.add(button1);

    JButton buttonc = new JButton("C");
    buttonc.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            value2.setText("");
            value1.setText("");
            actionRecieved.setText("");
            value3.setText("");
        }
    });
    buttonc.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    buttonc.setBounds(293, 392, 69, 70);
    contentPane.add(buttonc);

    JButton button0 = new JButton("0");
    button0.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            value1.setText(value1.getText()+0);
        }
    });
    button0.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    button0.setBounds(105, 392, 69, 70);
    contentPane.add(button0);

    JButton buttoneql = new JButton("=");
    buttoneql.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            int one = Integer.parseInt(value2.getText());
            int two = Integer.parseInt(value1.getText());

            if(actionRecieved.getText().equals("sub"))
            {
                int sub = one - two;
                value3.setText(String.valueOf(sub));

            }
            if(actionRecieved.getText().equals("add"))
            {
                int add = one + two;
                value3.setText(String.valueOf(add));

            }
            if(actionRecieved.getText().equals("mul"))
            {
                int mul = one * two;
                value1.setText(String.valueOf(mul));

            }
            if(actionRecieved.getText().equals("div"))
            {
                int div = one / two;
                value1.setText(String.valueOf(div));

            }
        }
    });
    buttoneql.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    buttoneql.setBounds(199, 392, 69, 70);
    contentPane.add(buttoneql);

    JButton buttonplus = new JButton("+");
    buttonplus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            value2.setText(value1.getText());
            actionRecieved.setText("plus");
            value1.setText(null);
        }
    });
    buttonplus.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    buttonplus.setBounds(12, 489, 69, 70);
    contentPane.add(buttonplus);

    JButton buttonminus = new JButton("-");
    buttonminus.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            value2.setText(value1.getText());
            actionRecieved.setText("sub");
            value1.setText(null);
        }
    });
    buttonminus.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    buttonminus.setBounds(105, 489, 69, 70);
    contentPane.add(buttonminus);

    JButton buttonmultiply = new JButton("x");
    buttonmultiply.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            value2.setText(value1.getText());
            actionRecieved.setText("mul");
            value1.setText(null);
        }
    });
    buttonmultiply.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    buttonmultiply.setBounds(199, 489, 69, 70);
    contentPane.add(buttonmultiply);

    JButton buttondivide = new JButton("/");
    buttondivide.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            value2.setText(value1.getText());
            actionRecieved.setText("div");
            value1.setText(null);
        }
    });
    buttondivide.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    buttondivide.setBounds(293, 489, 69, 70);
    contentPane.add(buttondivide);



    value2 = new JTextField();
    value2.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    value2.setBorder(new SoftBevelBorder(BevelBorder.LOWERED, null, null, 
    null, null));
    value2.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    value2.setBounds(229, 29, 133, 41);
    contentPane.add(value2);
    value2.setColumns(10);


    JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane();
    editorPane.setEditable(false);
    editorPane.setBounds(12, 29, 350, 81);
    contentPane.add(editorPane);

    actionRecieved = new JLabel("");
    actionRecieved.setBounds(12, 572, 118, 48);
    contentPane.add(actionRecieved);
    }
    private JLabel actionRecieved;
    }
```

Comment: wwhy are you doing ***int add = one1 + two1*** instead of  ***one+two***....???

Answer (score 4):

You have the following problems

1. For div `int div = one - two;` - should be `/`
2. For 1. you will have problem with Integer division
3. Add will never be entered into because you do `actionRecieved.setText("plus");` but expect `add`
4. Not sure why in some cases you are setting `value1` and in others `value3`
5. ???

Comment: I have developed the calc using swing components in eclipse using the drag and drop components

Comment: value1 and value2 are the variables for textfields and i replaced add with plus it worked thanks....

Comment: which answer should i accept the upper one that u told ?

Comment: there is only one answer